# Sgvizler: Create empty table for empty result

Tags: sgvizler

When I create a `sgvizler.visualization.Table` with Sgvizler 0.6 and the SPARQL query has no results, Sgvizler doesn't draw anything, not even the table header. This may confuse users who may think that the result is still being calculated or that the script has crashed. How can I configure Sgvizler to draw the table header even when the result is empty?

**Minimum Working Example**

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mgskjaeveland.github.io/sgvizler/v/0.6/sgvizler.js"></script>
     <script>
     sgvizler
     .defaultEndpointURL("https://dbpedia.org/sparql")
     .defaultChartFunction("sgvizler.visualization.Table")
     .defaultChartWidth(1000);
     $(document).ready(function (){ sgvizler.containerDrawAll(); });
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2>First Table</h2>
     <div id="results"
     data-sgvizler-query="
     select distinct ?class
     {
      ?class rdfs:subClassOf dbo:Animal.
     }
     ">
      </div>
      <h2>Second Table</h2>
     <div id="noresults"
     data-sgvizler-query="
     select distinct ?class
     {
      ?class rdfs:subClassOf dbo:Unicorn.
     }
     ">
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the parser, which looks only at the first row of results to build the JSON accepted by the google.visualization.DataTable object.

The solution would be to rewrite the parser to check the "column headers" of the SPARQL result set.

The parser is here: https://github.com/mgskjaeveland/sgvizler/blob/master/src/parser.js